# Symbols << & * in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

What's do `&build_project` and `<<: *build_project` mean? Do I understand right that this is a command to insert a chunk with the name of build_project to deploy stage?

```yaml
.build_project: &build_project
  tags:
    - docker
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  ...
  script:
  ...


deploy:
 variables:
   DEPLOY_HOST: ...
   DEPLOY_PATH: ...
   LOCAL_PATH: ...
 <<: *build_project
 only:
   - dev
```

Comment: In addition, [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html).

Comment: These are YAML features (not necessarily GitLab specific). This is covered partly in the [GitLab docs for optimizing configurations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html)